# Получение текста из буфера обмена с помощью ctypes

Tags: python, python-3.x, winapi, ctypes

У меня уже есть какой-то код для этого, но он все русские символы заменяет на `?`. Как можно такое поведение исправить, чтобы работало на всех языках? Преобразовать как-то в `utf-8`?

```
import ctypes

CF_TEXT = 1

kernel32 = ctypes.windll.kernel32
user32 = ctypes.windll.user32

user32.OpenClipboard(0)
if user32.IsClipboardFormatAvailable(CF_TEXT):
    data = user32.GetClipboardData(CF_TEXT)
    data_locked = kernel32.GlobalLock(data)
    text = ctypes.c_char_p(data_locked)
    for x in text.value:
        print(str(x))
    print(text.value)
    kernel32.GlobalUnlock(data_locked)
else:
    print('no text in clipboard')
user32.CloseClipboard()
```

По некоторым причинам, мне для этого подходит только `ctypes`. Ничего другого прошу не предлагать, я знаю, что в `win32clipboard` всё работает :)

Comment: А с форматом `CF_UNICODETEXT` (13) работает?

Comment: @MBo не совсем понимаю, о чём вы. Всегда писал высокоуровневый код, а тут вдруг нужно поменьше тяжелых библиотек.. Имеете в виду, все CF_TEXT заменить на CF_UNICODETEXT?

Comment: При копировании русского текста буфер обмена содержит несколько доступных форматов. Данные CF_TEXT будут в правильной кодировке (используется нужная кодовая страница), если в момент копирования установлена русская раскладка клавиатуры. А с юникодом такой проблемы нет.

Comment: Кодировка не та...

Comment: @MBo Ага, понял.. Буду дома - проверю и отпишу.